# isAuthenticated is always false after callback redirect to react localhost on a different port 3000 . Passport.js + React + Express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, session-cookies

User is successfully authenticated with Passport.js strategy but after callback redirect to React frontend running on different port, req.isAuthenticated is always false. Might be Cors issue in React + Express.js setup, or Passport.js bug

User is successfully authenticated after a Passport.js callback in Express.js. `IsAuthenticated` returns `True.` in `/success`

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  successRedirect: '/success',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}));



app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("Authenticated?", req.isAuthenticated());
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

After redirect to frontend I fetch authentication status from React, and it's false. Session object is there, but `req.user` is undefined

```
app.get('/api/auth/status', (req, res) => {
  // req.logIn();
  console.log('req cookies', req.cookies);
  console.log('req user', req.user);
  console.log("Auth status check: isAuthenticated:", req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("Authenticated user:", req.user);
    res.json({ isAuthenticated: true, user: req.user });
  } else {
    console.log("session", req.isAuthenticated());
    // res.json({ isAuthenticated: false });
     res.json({ isAuthenticated: false });
  }
});
```

I assumed it might be cors problem, but it seems to be working fine

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', 
  credentials: true,
}));



var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'your secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({ 
    mongoUrl: process.env.DB,
    collectionName: 'sessions'
  }),
  cookie: { 
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false, // Set to true if using https
    sameSite: 'lax'
  }
}));
```

Proxy in package.json `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` and server is running on 5000. Credentials are fetched correctly with Axious request . Session is there if you console log req.session, but user is not there.

My intuition it's either Passport.js bug or something wrong with Cors setup. I've also tried looking into Serialise and Deserialise functions, but they correctly return the user object . The whole passport flow seems to be working fine until redirect to localhost.

I assume cors is working fine, because other api request are working correctly.